# How to use same android button to start an activity and do a function in previous activity?

Tags: android, button

I have an SMS application.Here i wish to use the send button to send sms in that activity as well as move on to new activity.I have written code to send sms.But dono how to go to another activity at the same time.Kindly help.This is the code.

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {     

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {

                    String mobileno=pno.getText().toString();
                    String text=msg.getText().toString();
                    sentsms(mobileno,text);

                }

            });
```

Comment: You should include an Intent after sending the SMS and start it

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourSecondActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

In your onClick, this would be:

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {     

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                String mobileno=pno.getText().toString();
                String text=msg.getText().toString();
                sentsms(mobileno,text);

                Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourSecondActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Please look at the code below:

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {     

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {

                    String mobileno=pno.getText().toString();
                    String text=msg.getText().toString();
                    sentsms(mobileno,text);

                    // start other activity here
                    Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this,
                        YourOtherActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);

                }

            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
  btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {     

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            String mobileno=pno.getText().toString().trim();
            String text=msg.getText().toString().trim();
            sentsms(mobileno,text);

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourActivityName.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

 });
```